# Shorthand if else in PHP with multiple lines

Tags: php

I can't seem to find out what the exact control structures are for PHP if/else.

Currently I have this function but can anyone tell me if PHP is just looking for the "tabs"? And is it possible to trigger multiple functions within just 1 statement? Like now its just redirecting to a route but lets say I want to like email a user when hes updated before the redirect. Is this still possible with shorthand?

```
public function store()
{
    return ($user = $this->user->store(Input->all())) ?

        Redirect::route('user.index')
            ->with('flash_message', 'User succesfully created!', ['user' => $user]) :

        Redirect::route('user.create')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($this->user->getErrors());
}
```

Comment: Stop making the code unreadable. What benefit are you getting from using shorthand in this case? Nothing really.

Comment: @crypticツ perfect username for that comment ;)

Comment: Ternary operator should only be used with short logic for variable assignment in my opinion

Comment: @crypticツ It looks like this wasn't written by Floris, since he is looking for help to understand it!

Comment: Not sure about what those "tabs" are but you can certainly write lots of code in the same statement (e.g.: `foo() && $bar() && gee()` and make all them return `true`) but people call that obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the documentation for php if/else:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

`? :` structure is a shorthand for if/else, but it isn't a good practice to use it for complex things. It makes your code unreadable. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Otherwise php doesn't care about whitespaces.

Comment: It's a shorthand for if/else... when you have a variable assignment. Yesterday I saw it used in this very site like this: `!isset($x) ? $err='Not X' : $err='';`

Comment: You can use for much more things, but it is hacky, so you shouldn't. (...)?{...}:{...} is nearly the same as if(...){...}else{...}. The first one has a return value, and the second is stackable easier with elseifs.

Answer (score 0):

With if/else, it would look like this:

```
public function store()
{
    if ($user = $this->user->store(Input->all()))
    {
        return Redirect::route('user.index')
            ->with('flash_message', 'User succesfully created!', ['user' => $user]);
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::route('user.create')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($this->user->getErrors());
    }
}
```

It would be easier to read still if the `if` didn't do the assignment. eg:

```
public function store()
{
    $user = $this->user->store(Input->all())

    if ($user)
    {
        return Redirect::route('user.index')
            ->with('flash_message', 'User succesfully created!', ['user' => $user]);
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::route('user.create')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($this->user->getErrors());
    }
}
```